# Using Covariant Generic Types in Methods

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I'm practising my covariance, trying to get my head around it all.

I've developed two similar methods, a invariant one which works pretty much how you would expect, but lacks some advanced type functionality, and a covariant one which is giving me an error.

```
#region Animals
public abstract class Animal { };

public class Lemur : Animal { };

#endregion

public interface IExhibit<out T> where T : Animal
{
}

#region Poster
public interface IPoster<out T> where T : Animal
{
    string GetHeadline();
}

public class Poster<T> : IPoster<T> where T : Animal
{
    public string GetHeadline()
    {
        return typeof(T).ToString();
    }
}
#endregion

public class Zoo
{
    List<IExhibit<Animal>> exhibits;
    List<Poster<Animal>> posters;

    public void AddExhibit(IExhibit<Animal> newExhibit) //option 1
    {
        exhibits.Add(newExhibit);
        posters.Add(new Poster<Animal>()); //poster will just say "animal"
    }

    public void AddExhibit<T>(IExhibit<T> newExhibit) where T : Animal
    {
        exhibits.Add(newExhibit);
        posters.Add(new Poster<T>());
    }
}
```

Hopefully it is intuitive enough what I am trying to do. I know there are lots of hacky ways to do this, but since I'm more interested in the theory, I'm trying to get this type of thing working. The whole premise is that

```
public void AddExhibit<T>(IExhibit<T> newExhibit) where T : Animal
```

is more useful than

```
public void AddExhibit(IExhibit<Animal> newExhibit)
```

because it is more specific, and I want to utilise the fact that you have access to type T. I just got to get the covariance working. I suspect the issue is that I'm using Poster instead of IPoster but since IPoster is an interface you can't instantiate it.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Use the interface for list of posters (e.g. `List<IPoster<Animal>> posters;`). Then you could do `posters.Add(new Poster<T>());` Interfaces allow variance, classes do not.